# Applescript only working on 1 of 2 similar macs

Tags: applescript

Weird result when running same script on similar macs:

```
-- write to textfile
on txt_write_to_file(theTextfile, theText, doAppend)
    set theFile to open for access theTextfile as text with write permission

    set appendthis to true
    if doAppend is false then
        set eof theFile to 0
    end if

    set theResult to writetext (theText as string) & return ¬
        to theFile ¬
        append appendthis ¬
        encoding "UTF-8"

    close access theFile
end txt_write_to_file
```

While it works fine on the one 
`10.10.4` Mac with `Script editor Version 2.7` (176)
it results in the following error message on the other
`10.10.5` Mac with `Script editor Version 2.7` (176)
(no plugins on both)

```
"Expected end of line, etc. but found “to”."
```

-> thats the line with "set theResult ....... to thefile"

Tried without line breaks - no success.

Really appreciate your help ! Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

The command `writetext` is part of the Scripting Addition `Satimage.osax`.
If `Satimage.osax` is not installed in `(~)/Library/ScriptingAdditons`, you get an error.

Comment: Thank you very much, Vadian.